# $translatePartialLoader get prefferdLanguage doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, translation

I have one main app with few Independent components that each component loading its own strring files.
I want that in the main app config I will define the preferrd language and in each component I will use this prefferd language.

Setter:

```
$translateProvider.uses('en_EN');
```

Getter:

```
 $translate.uses() === 'en_EN'? $translate.uses('de_DE') : $translate.uses('en_EN');
```

I know that i cant use $translate in the config

```
 $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: './{part}/strings_{lang}.json'
        });

        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('assets');
```

How can i get prefferdlanguage using translatePartialLoaderProvider?
How can i Know what is the prefferd language set in the main app?

Answer (score 1):

The solution:
since in the app config you cannot know what is the prefferd language (that data is in $translate) you can get that data in app run:

```
.config(['$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider',  function ( $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
        'use strict';

        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('./niceComponents/nice-add-and-edit-inut-text/dist/asstes/src');

        //default lang that will change in run
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');

    }])
    .run(['$translate' , function($translate){
        var lan = $translate.preferredLanguage();
        console.log('lan---- ' + lan);
        $translate.use(lan);
        $translate.refresh();
    }])
```